# React - Loop inside a loop not rendering

Tags: reactjs, loops, render

I have a map loop inside another loop like this:

```
{"undefined" !== typeof this.props.categoryObject['products'] && Object.keys(this.props.categoryObject['products']).length > 0 && Object.keys(this.props.categoryObject['products']).map(keyProd => {
    const product = this.props.categoryObject['products'][keyProd];
    if("undefined" !== typeof product) {
        Object.keys(this.props.activeFilters).map(keyFilter => {     
            console.warn(this.props.activeFilters[keyFilter]);
            return (<div>test</div>)
        })
    }
})}
```

The console works, but not the render. Any idea why ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem here that outer `.map` doesn't have `return` statement and your outer code doesn't have `return` statement too.

So you have to change your code to the following

```
return ("undefined" !== typeof this.props.categoryObject['products'] && Object.keys(this.props.categoryObject['products']).length > 0 && Object.keys(this.props.categoryObject['products']).map(keyProd => {
    const product = this.props.categoryObject['products'][keyProd];
    if("undefined" !== typeof product) {
        return Object.keys(this.props.activeFilters).map(keyFilter => {     
            console.warn(this.props.activeFilters[keyFilter]);
            return (<div>test</div>)
        })
    }
}))
```

Also some notes on how you can make your code more readable with new es6 features. Commented version

```
// It's better to extract products into separate variable 
// as there are a lot of copy paste code for this action
const { products } = this.props.categoryObject;

// `undefined` is falsy value so you can just test next condition for early exit
if (!products) { return null; }

// 1. no need to test for `.length` as iterating empty array will make 0 iterations
// 2. use Object.entries you can immediately get key and value
return Object.entries(products).map(([key, product]) => {
  // Same things as with `products` variable
  if (product) {
    // I think for your future code you can use `Object.entries` here too
    return Object.keys(this.props.activeFilters).map(keyFilter => {     
      return (<div>test</div>)
    })
  }
})
```

Final version:

```
const { products } = this.props.categoryObject;
if (!products) { return null; }

return Object.entries(products).map(([key, product]) => {
  if (product) {
    return Object.keys(this.props.activeFilters).map(keyFilter => {     
      return (<div>test</div>)
    })
  }
})
```

**NOTE** to use all of them in all common browser you have to configure your `babel` properly